# When an Hilbert–Schmidt operator is invertible? How to construct the kernel of the inverse?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, integral-transforms, differential-operators

This question is motivated by the following example.
I have the following integral operator defined on $L^2(\mathbb{T}^n)\to L^2(\mathbb{T}^n) $
$$ T f(x) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}^n} \sigma(k,x) \ \hat{f}(k) e^{ik\cdot x} $$
where $\hat f(k)$ is the $k$-Fourier coefficent of $f$,  and $\sigma(k,\cdot)$  is invertible for any $k\neq O$.
For example, if $\sigma$ do not depend on $x$,  we get a multiplication operator
$$ T f(x) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}^n} \sigma(k) \ \hat{f}(k) e^{ik\cdot x} $$
thanks to the assumption that $\sigma(k)$ is invertible we can construct an inverse of $T$ (I am not interested in continuity for now).
This suggested  me to formally invert the general $T$ as

$$A g(x)=  \sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{\sigma(k,x)} \hat g (k)e^{i k\cdot x} $$
I do not see, though, a simple manner to prove that this constitutes an inverse (at least where defined).

> > 1)Consider an integral operator of the form 
> >     $$Tf(x) = \int_X f(y)K(y,x)d\mu(y)$$
> >     from $L^2(X,\mu)$ to itself.
> >     I wonder how, and under which hypothesis,   we can construct a formal inverse using the kernel $K$.
> >
> > 2) Consider the operator defined above on $L^2(\mathbb{T}^n)$, the one in the form
> >     $$ T f(x) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}^n} \sigma(k,x) \ \hat{f}(k) e^{ik\cdot x},$$
> >     how can we construct a formal inverse?
> >
> > 3) If we have an integral transform with kernels $K$ which is invertible with $K^{-1}$ kernel of the inverse, can we construct a formal inverse of 
> >     $$ Tf(x) = \int_X\int_X f(y) K(y,\xi) K^{-1}(x,\xi)\sigma(x,\xi) d\mu(y) d\mu(\xi)$$
> >     ?

This question is motivated by an assertion that I have found that suggests that if a  linear differential operator $D:C^{\infty}(\mathbb{T}^n)\to C^{\infty}(\mathbb{T}^n) $ is elliptic, then, we can construct an inverse of $D$ restricted to non-constant functions.

Comment: The operator $A$ that you define in your third equation is not a "formal inverse" of the operator $T$ that you define in the first line, but, if I recall correctly, they are inverses of each other "up to an smoothing operator" meaning that the composition will be the $id$ with a smooth correction term. You should look a text in pseudodifferential operator, like Taylor's Pseudodifferential operators and nonlinear PDE's or Stein's Harmonic analysis, Chapter VI.